# "Published at..." or "published on d/m/y"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, dates

I need to name a column in a table and I'm wondering what the best option is.

Should it be "Published at + date + time" or "Published on"?

I only need to store a full date and time.

From some search I did, it seems that *published at* is used when referencing a date in the future while *published on* is used to reference a full date in the past,  however it doesn't seem to be universal.

Any advice?

Answer (score 12):

I would use *on* for a date:

> This was published on July 4, 2007.

and I would use *at* for a time:

> That was published at 1:30 PM.

So, for a column that has a date and time, either preposition would sound both fitting and awkward at the same time, at least to my ears.

Why not simply name the column ***Published***, sans a preposition?  If you don't like that idea, you could use ***When Published***.

Comment: And then of course there's *timestamp*.

Comment: What if it's for a year only? Is it correct to write "*This was published in 2007*"?

Comment: @galacticninja: Correct. Use _in_ for years. You can also use _in_ for a month without a specified date as well: _This was published in November 2003._

Comment: In programming database table columns sometimes have already pre created names like `createdAt`, `modifiedAt`, `deletedAt`. Following the pattern, I'd add `publishedAt` even if I only needed day or month out of this date. And I'd disregard if it sounded strange, because it's more important to remember the name of the column quickly.

Answer (score 3):

It's been customary to name columns in passive voice, e.g. Publishing date/time. That way no matter what values in your data, the column name will be correct.

Comment: This is actually either active voice or (in my view) a gerund. But good advice nevertheless.

Comment: Sorry. Noun phrase is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, *on* seems to be the widely accepted preposition for dates. However, just to expand on @J.R.'s suggestion, I would use neither of them in a database column and go with the following alternatives:

> Date Published(date_published)

Or if you want to follow [Wordpress's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) naming style, then use the following:

> If the table name is *comment*, name the column *comment date*(comment_date).